# laravel 5.3 session not persisting

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.3

i have a problem with laravel session :

```
Route::get("/set",function(){
    session(["s1"=>'foo']);
    Session::save();
    dump(Session::all());
    dump(session("s1"));
    exit;
});
```

the first dump result is like this :

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "YbH1A9frXuUsk6O01IdshL1rXmih2GtpiRXdvZoC"
  "s1" => "foo"
  "_sf2_meta" => array:3 [▶]
  "_flash" => array:2 [▶]
]
```

and the second:

```
"foo"
```

ok .. everything is ok , but when i go to second route like bellow problem occurred :

```
Route::get("/read",function(){
    dump(session("s1"));
    dump(Session::all());
    exit;
});
```

the result is like this , first dump :

```
null
```

and second dump :

```
array:1 [▼
  "_token" => "LVH9mnoWVRfiAuFkIbEgEWr56hgLpityuHCJTBj3"
]
```

please help me ...

Comment: Different `_token` means the session is not the same. Check your cookies in both requests to make sure you're sending the correct one and it's not being deleted or something

Comment: Is the storage path writable?

Comment: @Devon yes that is writable

Comment: @apokryfos yes you are right .. each time i read session _token will change..